# Get a number of rows retrieved by a view

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I've created a view to retrieve stuff from a database. I need to create some kind of a counter that would return the total number of records that came from this view and implement that in c#. What are ways to do that? Maybe it is possible to add counter inside the view or...? 
I'm pretty new to sql and oracle in particulat and I'd appreciate your tips on the matter.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM your_view;`

Comment: @MT0 You may be better off with `COUNT(1)` rather than `COUNT(*)` in case the view returns any rows in which all columns are NULL.

Comment: @Unoembre: try `select count(*) from ( select null from dual)`

Comment: @Aleksej Thanks, you are correct, `COUNT(*)` and `COUNT(1)` seem to be equivalent when counting rows rather than then contents of a individual column.

Comment: A view is just a stored query. It doesn't store the data anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get record count from view as below:

## SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as RecordCount FROM Your_ViewName
```

Now in ADO.NET C# you can use ExecuteScalar() method and get count of records generated from your SQL-View.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a table with some data and then created a view. Check the same.

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
(id int, productName varchar(7),)
```

;

```
INSERT INTO ForgeRock(id,productName) VALUES(1, 'OpenIDM');
INSERT INTO ForgeRock(id,productName) VALUES(2, 'FK');
INSERT INTO ForgeRock(id,productName) VALUES(3, 'SD');
INSERT INTO ForgeRock(id,productName) VALUES(4, 'AM');

CREATE VIEW testView as Select id from ForgeRock;


Select COUNT(*) from testview
```